# how to echo command (make a file) - batch file

Tags: batch-file

I am trying to make a batch file which makes batch files...
so..

```
1  :start
2  echo :start > txtfilemaker.bat
3  echo echo hoi > hoi.txt >> txtfilemaker.bat
4  echo echo done >> txtfilemaker.bat
5  echo pause >> txtfilemaker.bat
```

this is a fast example, but how can I do line 3 of the script?

If anyone understands me, THNX!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a caret (`^`) to quote your redirection character:

```
echo echo hoi ^> hoi.txt >> txtfilemaker.bat
```

Without `>> txtfilemaker.bat` it would output

```
echo hoi > hoi.txt
```